# Double V-Model in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a Range Slider [veeno](http://veeno.surge.sh/)

and i whant return 2 values in template, min value and max value
In the model, I can only bind to one parameter, but I need several, such as the maximum value and minimum value
How do I implement a dual v-model?

This my template

```
veeno(
    connect
    v-model="getParamsJson.price"

    :tooltips="[true, true]"
    :handles="getParamsJson.price.handles"
    :range = "getParamsJson.price.range"
    :step="100"
)

| {{ getParamsJson.price }}
```

This my *data()*

```
getParamsJson = {"date": setDate,
    "price": {
        "handles" : [2000, 2650],
        "range" : { 'min': 1300, 'max': 3250 }
    },
}
```

Comment: `v-model` is just sugar syntax. Try using regular `:value` and `@input`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have more than one two-way bindings you can use the `.sync` modifier:

```html
<MyCustomSlider :min-value.sync="currentMinimal" :max-value.sync="currentMaximal" />
```

```js
export default
{
  props:
  {
    minValue:
   {
     type: Number,
     default: 0
   },
   maxValue:
   {
     type: Number,
     default: 0
   },
  },
  computed:
  {
    currentMin:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.minValue;
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.$emit('update:min-value', val);
      }
    },
    currentMax:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.maxValue;
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.$emit('update:max-value', val);
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: `.sync` was never a top recommendation and is not available anymore in Vue3. Since it's now the default and Nuxt3 is already at RC3, I'm not sure that recommending it is still wise. OP may need to refacto some logic when he will migrate.

Comment: @kissu The OP specifically tagged his question as `Vue 2` rather than `Vue 3`. `sync` is simply a syntactic sugar - just as `v-model` is. I don't see a reason not to use the shortcut when it's in place and saves typing.